# How to create the 'web' folder for a symfony installation

Tags: symfony, composer-php

When a new **Symfony2** Project is created using, `composer create-project` the `web/` folder containing **Front Controllers, .htaccess** is automatically created. Now I have got my Symfony2 Project under **Git**, but I have not committed the `web/` dir, as they are platform dependent in my case, and the default versions can be generated. However running `composer install` on a clone of the project (containing the `app/` and `src/` folders and `composer.*` files) won't generate the `web/` dir. Now, how do I tell Composer to do that?

Comment: What would the expected output be like? If the `web` directory is platform dependent, how would your composer script know how to generate the directory? Maybe you could write a script using `post-install-cmd`.

Comment: @StephanVierkant, I want composer to generate the default `web/` directory as it does when starting a new Symfony Project.(`composer create-project`)

Comment: Why don't you add the directory to your git repository and delete/change it when needed? I don't think generating using `composer install` is the best option.

Comment: It's really tough keeping different versions of the same file on different machines when they're supposed to be maintained under the same git repository. e.g: a lot of trouble with merging and stuff.

Comment: As you can see on Symfony's official repository, (https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/.gitignore) "web" dir is usually added to your code repo, it is easiest. 

If you don't like that, better way to do this is composer using post-install-cmd, maybe you could download web folder from symfony repo and copy it to your proyect folder.

Answer (score 2):

The web directory is created from the symfony-standard repository, composer can't create the content on every install but you can make something custom by adding a "post-install-cmd" or "post-update-cmd" inside your composer.json file.

have a look at what's done inside the `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles method`